# A regular expression using a list of words

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python.

I have some strings :

```
'1 banana', '100 g of sugar', '1 cup of flour'
```

I need to distinguish the food from the quantity.
I have an array of quantities type

`quantities = ['g', 'cup', 'kg', 'L']
altern = '|'.join(quantities)`

and so with using a regular expression I would like to get for example for `'1 cup of flour'` : `'flour'` and `'1 cup of'`, for `'1 banana'` : `'1'` and `'banana'`

I have written this regexp to match the quantity part of the strings above :

```
\d{1,3}\s<altern>?\s?(\bof\b)?
```

but I'm very unsure about this ...particularly on how to introduce the altern variable in the regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `amounts` are `units`, so I took the liberty to fix this misnomer.  I propose to use named grouping to ease understanding the output.

```
import re

units = [ 'g', 'cup', 'kg', 'L' ]
anyUnitRE = '|'.join(units)

inputs = [ '1 banana', '100 g of sugar', '1 cup of flour' ]

for input in inputs:
  m = re.match(
    r'(?P<amount>\d{1,3})\s*'
    r'(?P<unit>(' + anyUnitRE + r')?)\s*'
    r'(?P<preposition>(of)?)\s*'
    r'(?P<name>.*)', input)
  print m and m.groupdict()
```

The output will be sth like this:

```
{'preposition': '', 'amount': '1', 'name': 'banana', 'unit': ''}
{'preposition': 'of', 'amount': '100', 'name': 'sugar', 'unit': 'g'}
{'preposition': 'of', 'amount': '1', 'name': 'flour', 'unit': 'cup'}
```

So you can do sth like this:

```
if m.groupdict()['name'] == 'sugar':
  …
amount = int(m.groupdict()['amount'])
unit = m.groupdict()['unit']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this:

```
"(.*?) (\w*)$"
```

And get `\1` for first part and `\2` for second part.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/wG0dO1/1)

And for a better regex:

```
"^((?=.*of)((.*of)(.*)))|((?!.*of)(\d+)(.*))$"
```

And get `\3` and `\6` for first part and `\4` and `\7` for second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import re
lst = ['1 banana', '100 g of sugar', '1 cup of flour']
quantities = ['g', 'cup', 'kg', 'L']
altern = '|'.join(quantities)
r = r'(\d{1,3})\s*((?:%s)?s?(?:\s*\bof\b)?\s*\S+)'%(altern)
for x in lst:
    print re.findall(r, x)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/h0hEZH)

Output:

```
[('1', 'banana')]
[('100', 'g of sugar')]
[('1', 'cup of flour')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this with regular expressions? You can use Python's string splitting functions instead:

```
def qsplit(a):
    """Return a tuple of quantity and ingredient"""

    if not a:
        return None

    if not a[0] in "0123456789":
        return ["0", a]

    if " of " in a:
        return a.split(" of ", 1)

    return a.split(None, 1)
```