# Extract word from a given list of words out of a string using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Using regular expressions, I wanted to extract certain words (such as street direction abbreviations, 'East', 'NW', or 'North West' etc.) from a string (such as an address). The words are from a fixed list (array) and are separated from each other by white spaces.

The closest thing I could find is to extract one word (units of quantity) in a list from a string ([A regular expression using a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31788566)) using python. But I am using SQL. Also, the words there follow a specific order/pattern. In my case, the words to be extracted can be anywhere in the string (beginning or near the end).

My question is:

*Is it possible to extract all occurrences of words in the list from a string using regexp* (hopefully without looping)?

I use SQL/PostgreSQL, and any standard regexp that can be converted to PostgreSQL regexp would be great too.

An example array is:
`ARRAY['east', 'south', 'west', 'north']`

Comment: You could match the regex `\b(?:[eE]ast|[wW]est|[nN]orth|[sS]outh)\b`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNmJMw/1). You will have to use methods of the language you are using to extract the matches into an array. With Ruby, for example, if `str` is a variable holding the string of interest, you would write `str.scan(/\b(?:[eE]ast|[wW]est|[nN]orth|[sS]outh)\b/)`. Other languages have comparable methods or functions. Not that I am allowing the first letter of the compass direction to be upper or lower case, but requiring the remaining letters to be lower case. You may need to modify that.